# Vba automatisé activité tracking date

Tags: excel, vba

[picture of the first code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjS1R.jpg) [picture of the seconde  code [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxYYS.jpg)I am trusting to update the date of the sheet a duplicate from the precious sheet. But I don’t know how to change the date of juin to juillet to August until Decembe.
How can do .  How can update the date for it to change Evry time I change a months.

```vb
Sub CopierTableau()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim mois As Integer
    Dim annee As Integer
    Dim MoisActuel As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim currentDate As Date
    Dim MyWeekDay As Integer
    
    mois = Month(Date)
    annee = Year(Date)
    
    For i = mois + 1 To 12
        MoisActuel = MonthName(i)
        lastRow = Sheets(MoisActuel).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets(MoisActuel).Range("A1:GP" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets(i).Range("A1")
        ChangerDates i
    Next i
End Sub

Sub ChangerDates(i As Integer)
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Set Rng = Sheets(i).Range("B1:FN1")
        
    For Each cell In Rng
        If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
            If Month(cell.Value) = i Then
                cell.Value = DateAdd("m", 1, cell.Value)
                cell.Value = DateSerial(Year(cell.Value), Month(cell.Value), Day(cell.Value))
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please *edit your question* to add the code there - code in comments is pretty much unreadable.

Comment: année means years and mois means months

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code - no-one can test fixes without first having to type it all out, and no-one is going to do that.

Comment: @aissatoubah - you edited your post but have still failed to provide the code in the body of your question. Pictures of code are not useful - we need to be able to copy and paste the actual code itself in order to help you.